# Ganesha Chathurthi in Bhadrapad or Magha month?

Tags: ganesha, festivals

Someone today told me that Ganesha chathurthi, birthday of Ganesha, is not in Bhadrapada month but in Magha.
What does Puranas say about Ganesha's birth (or the day He was made the lord of Ganas) month/thithi?

Answer (score 0):

Bhadrapada Shukla Chatruti (4th expansion of Moon) is the day Ganesha Chaturti. This is a Vrutanta (event) associated with this day and is present in both Mahabharatam and in Vishnu Purana of Rishi Parashara. This Vrutanta (event) includes Sri Krishna, Satrajith (father in-law of Sri Krishna), Jambhavanta (the one born from the yawn of Lord Brahma), the Gem called Shamantaka bestowed by Lord Surya to Satrajith, and Chandra (moon). This Vrutanta is called Shamantakopanyam and is read/heard on this day. Sankata Hara Chaturti is an event that comes into every Masam (month).

Comment: "is the day Ganesha has manifested.". Please quote Bharata or Purana where it's mentioned. Otherwise, it's not an answer but an opinion.

Comment: @Kanthri Read the second line. "This is a Vrutanta (event) associated with this day and is present in both Mahabharatam and in Vishnu Purana of Rishi Parashara."

Comment: Understood. Please quote the passage from Bharata or Purana... specifically about Ganesha's birth in this day.